# Regex offset in string

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I am currently using a regular expression to find some data in a given string.I wish to find the position of the matching pattern in the string.

Is it possible to find the offset of a Regex in a given string with FreePascal ?

Answer (score 2):

In current versions there are two regex functions. One is only in newer versions, but is the most commonly used one (Sorokin's regexpr). And older unit regex is faster but more limited iirc.

I don't use regular expressions much, so I don't have example syntax for you. There is some information here in the wiki http://wiki.freepascal.org/Regexpr though

Of course you could also try to create a header for the perl pcre library. (or recycle a Delphi one)

However to find the offset a simple substring, one can use the standard POS() function. THere is a replace function too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the standard RegExpr unit.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$IFDEF FPC}{$MODE DELPHI}{$ENDIF}

uses
  regexpr;

var
  s: string;
  e: TRegExpr;

begin
  s := 'abcdefg';

  e := TRegExpr.Create;
  e.Expression := '[c-f]+';
  e.Exec(s);

  WriteLn(e.Match[0]);    // cdef
  WriteLn(e.MatchPos[0]); // 3
  WriteLn(e.MatchLen[0]); // 4

  e.Free;

  ReadLn;
end.
```